# How to determine the negative index of an element in a list?

Tags: python, list

How can I see the negative index of an element in a list in python `list.index()` will only return the positive index. How do I get the negative index of it?

Comment: negative index counts from the back of the list. So to get negative index of an element, you can subtract the length of the list from the positive index.

Answer (score 0):

A negative index is the index from the end of the list. You could calculate it by subtracting the length of the list from the positive index:

```py
postive_index = some_list.index('some_value')
negative_index = positive_index - len(some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple custom logic for this for example:

1. get the index of the item
2. subtract the length of the list from this value

**Code**

```
my_list = [x*2 for x in range(10)]
my_item = 12
print('list: ', my_list)
print('index: ', my_list.index(my_item))
neg_index = my_list.index(my_item) - len(my_list)
print('negative index: ', neg_index)
print('indexed item: ', my_list[neg_index])
```

**Output**

```
list:  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
index:  6
negative index:  -4
indexed item:  12
```